# Bayesian probability re: people vs. coins

Tags: probability, bayesian

Imagine you're a court clerk recording information about court appearances in a munincipal court. Past records show that on a typical day in this court, in 50% of criminal cases heard, the accused defendant is Black. Just before the last case on a given day, you notice that eight (80%) of ten criminal cases heard by the court on that day involve Black defendants. The last case to be heard is also a criminal case. What is the probability that the defendant is this last case is Black?

Is the computation in this problem the same as the computation in this next problem?

You're witnessing someone flip a coin. On eight (80%) of ten coin flips, the coin lands heads. Past records show that this coin lands heads 50% of the time. This coin will be flipped one last time. What is the probability that the result of this last coin flip will also be heads?

Comment: The independence assumption that is natural for coins is less automatic in the other example. But without additional information, it is still plausible.

Comment: Let's assume one defendant's race has no bearing on the race of another defendant. In that case, the answer to both questions (people vs. coins) should be the same. But what is the answer and how it computed using Bayes Theorem?

Comment: In the case of coins at least, I do not view a prior/posterior analysis as useful, and would not budge from $50\%$. But it will be nice to see Bayesian answers.

Comment: So both problems are computationally equivalent, but the superficial differences (people vs. coin flips, both assuming independence) change how applicable Bayes' Theorem is? So is the answer to the first/people question also 0.5?

Comment: Well, I would urge caution about the independence assumption, and some computation is useful to test the independence, though a sample of $10$ is of no use at all. As an instance of the  independence issue, there are reports of arrests of likely non-Bush voters in the manipulated Florida vote.

Comment: Again let's assume independence for the purposes of these two problems. And from a Bayesian perspective, wouldn't posterior probabilities change (although not by much) even with as small a sample as 10?

Comment: From a Bayesian perspective, yes, but I do not have a Bayesian perspective. In the case of coins, it would seem to me peculiar to update probabilities at each toss of the coin.

Comment: Assuming independence and the same sample size (N = 10), would it seem peculiar to update probabilities when a new defendant and his/her race becomes known?